# Show/ Hide a data field and a lable for some records in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to show or hide a field for some records according to condition in crystal report?
I'm using crystal report with VS 2005 C#
my report will look like this.

```
Bill No.     : B0012510
Customer     : AA Company
Cashier      : Test
Cancelled By : User1
Item Name   Price   Qty Amount
---------   -----   --- ------
Item1       100 3    300
Item2       500 2   1000
--------------------------------------
            Total   1300

Bill No.     : B0012511
Customer     : BB Company
Cashier      : Test2

Item Name   Price   Qty Amount
---------   ------  --- ------
Item3       100 3   300
Item4         50    2   100
--------------------------------------
            Total   400
```

Want to hide 'cancelled by' if that bill is not cancelled (cancel status=0) like second bill.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Crystal report designer, select the field you want to hide  + Right mouse click to open `Format object` + Common + Check the `Suppress` and open format formula editor and an expression like:

```
{tableName.cancelstatus}=0
```